# SQL how to store an unknown length list of items?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, database

For example for a user he could be a truck driver, a cleaner and a forklift driver. While another user could be just a pilot. And a user can have any number of jobs.

How would I insert this into the database without using another table.

In addition I would need to query through all the data, for example look for all the users who are truck drivers.

I am using rails if that makes any differences

Comment: *"How would I insert this into the database without using another table"* « easy, don't. This is exactly what you would use a junction table for. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: What do you mean by this "How would I insert this into the database without using another table."?

Comment: Maybe an array of somesort?